# Check and replace the values in each cell of a DataTable using ItemArray

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have a `datatable` with 10 columns. I have to check if the cell values in each of the columns contains value A or D, if so I have to replace 'A' with '150' and 'D' with '250' respectively.

I am trying with this ::

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
{
    foreach(var item in dr.ItemArray)
        {
            if( item.ToString()=="A")
            {
                item.ToString().Replace("A", "150");
            }
            if (item.ToString() == "D")
            {
                item.ToString().Replace("A", "250");
            }
        }
}
```

but the values are not replaced. Why is it so? What is the error with this code ?

Comment: It's not just about replacing a string. The question has another important point, which is ignored by the answerers. Assigning a value to an element of the item array or assigning value to a variable pointing to a column value is useless → `var item = row.Columns[i]; item = "something";` is **wrong**). They should replace the whole item array like this `row.ItemArray = anotherArray;` or assign something to the columns value directly: `row.Columns[i] = "something";`

Comment: Another important point when trying to replace the whole `ItemArray` property → If there is a read-only column, then setting item array will throw an exception.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank You for highlighting these points. Its helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing a string is not the whole point in the question. There are some important points, which are ignored by the other answers.

- Assigning a value to an element of the item array will not change column value.
- Assigning value to a variable containing the column value will not change the column value.
- To replace column values using `ItemArray`, you need to assign a new array the `ItemArray` property.
- When trying to replace the `ItemArray` property, if there is a read-only column, then setting item array will throw an exception.
- And the point which is already mentioned by other answers, `Replace` method of the string will return the result replaced string, it will not change the source string.

Just for your information to have a better understanding about `ItemArray` property, it's the way that the property works, (in short):

```
Public object[] ItemArray {
    get {
        var values = new object[Columns.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
            values[i] = Columns[i];
        }
        return values;
    }
    set {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
            //Checks if the column is writable and value is valid
            Columns[i] = value[i];
        }
    }
}
```

You can read the whole [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,c49b336f59c8f808) as well.

So as a conclusion, the following pieces of code are wrong and will do nothing for you:

- ***Wrong:*** `row.ItemArray[i] = "something";` *→ Will not change column[i]*
- ***Wrong:*** `var item = row[i]; item = "something";` *→ Will not change column[i]*
- ***Wrong*** `var s = "something"; s.Replace("s", "x");` *→ Will not change `s`.*

**Example - Using ItemArray**

Please be aware, if there is a read-only column in the data table, the following code will raise an exception:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    var a = r.ItemArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if ($"{a[i]}" == "A") // if($"{a[i]}".Contains("A"))
            a[i] = "150";     //     a[i] = $"{a[i]}".Replace("A", "150");
        if ($"{a[i]}" == "D")
            a[i] = "250";
    }
    r.ItemArray = a;
};
```

**Example - Using Columns Indexer**

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (c.ReadOnly)
            continue;
        if ($"{r[c]}" == "A") // if($"{r[c]}".Contains("A"))
            r[c] = "150";     //     r[c] = $"{r[c]}".Replace("A", "150");
        else if ($"{r[c]}" == "D")
            r[c] = "250";
    }
}
```